# Storing info from a database in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, database

Hi I need to work out the average of 10 integers stored in a database.

This is what I've got so far.

```
private void getAverage()
{
    StudentsDataSet.StudentsRow courseMarks = studentsDataSet.Students.Course[10];

    average = 0;
    int[] array;

    for (int index = 0; index < 10 ; index++)
    {
        average += array[index];
    }
    average = average / 10;
    averageBox.Text = average.ToString();           
}
```

As you can see I have no idea what I'm doing... any pointers??

Comment: Well, you are getting a `NullReferenceException` because you *declare* your `array` variable, you don't  *initialize* it. Before you can loop over the data you need to this with the array: declare the varible -> create the actual array -> fill the array with data.

Comment: `As you can see I have no idea what I'm doing` - Looks like you are on the right track.  Where are you having problems?

Comment: I have no idea if Im even on the right track. Also, There are rows in the database called Course1, Course2 up to... Course10, and I dont know how to specifically call those so what I have got is this studentsDataSet.Students.Course[10]

Comment: I guess I am having trouble 'Filling the array with data'

Comment: What's the DataStructure of `StudentsRow`

Comment: It's hard to help you with that if we don't know how the data looks. What's in your data table?

Comment: Ive added a screenshot of the data table in my original post

Comment: OK, we have the data now. One more thing: Could you please replace the image by some actual table? That would be much easer to read which increases your chances of getting help with the question.

Comment: Sorry I dont know what you mean

Comment: @JZGiraffe what is `StudentsDataSet.StudentsRow` ? is `courseMarks` holding marks on which you want to perform average ? `int[] array` doesnt hold any data. your loop will throw Null ref exception on very first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code, which I will address one by one:

- You are always getting the data from row 11 of your data table (`studentsDataSet.Students.Course[10]`). That's probably not what you want.
- You are *declaring* your array but you are not *initializing* it.
- You need to fill the array before you loop over it.
- You are repeating the number of courses (10) in many places in your code (e.g. the `for` loop and the divisor of the average). This will be a source of errors when the number of courses changes.
- Be careful to choose good names for your variables. `average` should be `sum` (that's what it actually stores) and `array` is a poor choice, because it does not describe the content of the variable, but its format.
- According to the C# naming convention methods are in PascalCase.

Here is some code that will do the job. I have added comments to explain exactly what is happening:

```
//The method that will add the average to the text box. You need to provide the row index.
//One common way to get the row index would be the SelectedIndex of your data grid
private void GetAverage(int rowIndex)
{
    //Get the row whose data you want to process
    DataRow courseMarks = studentsDataSet.Students.Rows[rowIndex];

    //Initialize an array with the names of the source columns
    string[] courseColumnNames = { "Course1", "Course2", "Course3", "Course4", "Course5",
        "Course6", "Course7", "Course8", "Course9", "Course10" };

    //Declare and initialize the array for the marks
    int[] markValues = new int[courseColumnNames.Length];

    //Fill the array with data
    for (int index = 0; index < courseMarks.Length ; index++)
    {
        //Get the column name of the current course
        string columnName = courseColumnNames[index];

        //Copy the column value into the array
        markValues[index] = (int)courseMarks[columnName];
    }

    //Calculate the sum
    int sum = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < courseMarks.Length ; index++)
    {
        sum += markValues[index];
    }

    //Calculate the average from the sum
    //Note: Since it's an integer division there will be no decimals
    int average = sum / courseMarks.Length;

    //Display the data
    averageBox.Text = average.ToString();           
}
```

Note that of course you could merge the two loops into one (and even drop the array, since you could just directly add to the `sum` variable). I have not done that to keep every step of the process clearly separated. You could also use the LINQ method `Average`, but that would quite miss the point here.

Comment: Thank you! Am I meant to add the row index in there or leave as you have written? Sorry for silly questions I have only been studying coding for 3 months

Comment: That's entirely up to what you want to do: Where does your row index come from? Is it a constant value or does it depend on user input? The method as it stands is complete. If you have a constant row index, pass it as a parameter. For best learning effect you should analize the gode line by line.

Comment: It is user input so do I need to put in: [FindByID1(Int32.Parse(searchIDtextbox.Text))];?

Comment: I don't know, because I don't know what `FindByID1` and `searchIDtextbox` are. In general, use your row index as an argument to the method, not in the method itself. I recommend you first call the method with a fixed value for the `rowIndex` parameter and execute the code step-by-step in the debugger. For each step, take a close look at the variables and their values (in VS, place the caret on the variable and press Shift-F9). Don't execute the next step until you have understood what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following :
`int average = studentsDataSet.Students.Course.Average();`
You would have to add `using System.Linq;` for this to work.

Comment: I guess the problem is I can't figure out how to get the 10 items from the database in there

Comment: ok. you should probably update the question with the same. Its not obvious from the question.

Comment: I have updated the answer, assuming that you already have the data in `studentsDataSet.Students.Course` array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all your codes, you may try this:

```
private double GetAverage()
{
    StudentsDataSet.StudentsRow courseMarks = studentsDataSet.Students.Course[10];
    var average=courseMarks.Average(x =>(double) x["*YourDataColumnName*"]);

    return average;
}
```

Where **YourDataColumnName** is the column of your row which contains the value you want to get average of that

Comment: Huh? You are gettting *one* value of *one* column. How would you get the average of that? And this is  not even working LINQ code.

Comment: @Sefe, What do you mean one value? I'm using the Average method, it's implemented on Enumerable